# Elevation color ramps for DEMs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, color-ramp

I need to color a DEM that I have loaded in QGIS 2.2.  I'd like the DEM colors to represent different elevations.

None of the color ramps that come with QGIS are related to elevation, so can anyone point me to pre-existing ramps that I can load in to QGIS?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

QGIS comes with a lot of colorramps but not all are enabled by default. It's covered in the [User Guide](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html#color-ramp):

> You can create a custom color ramp choosing New color ramp... from the color ramp drop-down menu. A dialog will prompt for the ramp type: Gradient, Random, colorBrewer, or cpt-city. The first three have options for number of steps and/or multiple stops in the color ramp. You can use the checkbox Invert option while classifying the data with a color ramp. See figure_symbology_3 for an example of custom color ramp and figure_symbology_3a for the cpt-city dialog.

[image]

**Update for QGIS 2.18:**
I have not found the updated link in the documentation, but `cpt-city` color ramp type are available:

First add a new ramp color as shown below:

[image]

Then, select the `cpt-city` option and you will find the many predefined palettes
[image]