# Color Ramp in QGIS

Tags: qgis, color, color-ramp

This is a real basic question, but I can't seem to find it. How do I add a color ramp in QGIS? I noticed that has different applications you can add to QGIS (like RdYlGn, GnYlRd, cpt-city, etc...) but I didn't find those in the plug-ins manager window. Could someone explain what are the main difference between those and How to install these add-ons?

I am using 2.14.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the menu `Settings - Style Manager` you can see the tag "Color ramp".

[image]

By clicking on the green plus you can add manually some color ramps or choose the `cpt-city` addon the allows you to choose between a lot of different color ramps.

Once you have defined your color-ramp (manually or by `cpt-city`) you can find it in each style menu (Raster and Vector).

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It was not obvious where to look for the predefined templattes, but I figured it out with the help of another question, the credits to this Q&A: [Elevation color ramps for DEMs in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94978/elevation-color-ramps-for-dems-in-qgis/94981#94981)

This is mainly about the predefined templattes from the library `cpt-city`, which has a bunch of nice templattes and is availbale within QGIS.

1. In the `Style`palette of the `Layer Properties` add a new ramp color as shown below:

[image]

2. Then, select the `cpt-city` option

[image]

3. Here you will find the many predefined palettes

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Right-click your raster to get the properties dialog of your raster.  Select style and set it to single-band pseudo color.  On the right-hand side of the dialog there is a set of controls which says "Generate new color map".  Click the drop-down to select a pre-existing gradient or scroll down to the bottom of the drop-down to choose 'New color map'.

Here you get a little dialog box where you can make your own or choose from a number of pre-made ones from ColorBrewer or cpt-city.  If you want to install a new ramp, search this site and you'll find further instructions (you can also specify them as SVG in another application and import those).